# "Request authorization tenant mismatch" when creating Teams call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

I get error
2019-12-31T08:15:00.418 [Error] Executed 'MeditationSpeaker' (Failed, Id=aeda98b3-4e1b-4faf-a1ea-d70779579d52) Code: 7505 Message: Request authorization tenant mismatch. Inner error: AdditionalData: request-id: a8a27ca8-d49a-49f5-9654-1ef61101aaeb date: 2019-12-31T08:15:00 ClientRequestId: a8a27ca8-d49a-49f5-9654-1ef61101aaeb

when trying to connect to Teams meeting according https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp I have set all permissions in Azure, Teams etc and cannot figure out what this "mismatch" means, since I'm giving the correct client id, secret and tenant id for the authentication provider

[Screenshot of the Azure Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhwTv.png)

I have created Bot Channel Registration, I have set permissions for the API

[Bot channel permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eITyx.png)

I have used App Studio to add the app to Teams

[Teams App Studio and attached bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayq6v.png)

If I don't give the tenant id in the code, then I got authorization error. But now, when I have all in place and done all what needs to be done, I get this "Request authorization tenant mismatch" and cannot figure out what to do.

[Azure Function error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZbao.png)

My application simple idea is to have a Azure Function entering every day to a Teams meeting and play an audio file. This is why I did not create a bot, I just want to use timer scheduled Azure Function

Cannot find anything with Google since this API for creating Teams call is totally new, release in December 2019

Please help, I have contacted O365 help, Azure help etc and they are just playing ping pong with each other stating that ticket does not belong to them

Comment: Finally found correct place to create ticket as a partner, it was under Benefits not Support. But anyway, if you have answer, please share 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3121537/using-technical-presales-and-deployment-services

Comment: I haven't had time to check this project, but I got this reply from MS:
Apology for late reply. Can you please make sure that you are not using the tenant ID that was used to register the bot. Instead you should use the tenant ID in the auth header that the bot received from Microsoft.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214894/error-7505-request-authorization-tenant-mismatch which handles teh same topic and describes a solution...

Comment: I need to check with Message Analyzer does it go there. I set the TenantId with C# to the class as instructed, but yes I have not checked does it go to the actual request