# Error 7505 - Request Authorization Tenant Mismatch

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am attempting to create a call using E[xample 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-create-a-group-call-with-service-hosted-media) from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). I consistently get the same `HTTP 403` response.

- My data is hosted via an Azure Portal Office Developer account.
- Sending  a bearer token obtained through the process described as ["Get access without a user."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0)
- The bot is defined in Azure AD using an Office 365 developer account.
- The recipients are two of the users from that free AD deployment and the 16-user pack installed for testing.

In the body of the `HTTP 403` response, I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "7505",
    "message": "Request authorization tenant mismatch.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "foo",
      "date": "2020-02-13T17:30:24"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The examples in the documentation seem to be missing a required `tenantId` property. Note that this property is mentioned in the documentation.

> The values of authorization token, callback URL, application ID, application name, user ID, user name, and **tenant ID** must be replaced with actual values to make the example work.

The [Example 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-3-create-a-group-call-with-service-hosted-media) from the Beta documentation, however, does seem to include this property in the request:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
  "direction": "",
  "subject": "",
  "callbackUri": ",
  "source": {...},
  "targets": [...],
  "requestedModalities": [...],
  "mediaConfig": {...},
  "tenantId": ""
}
```

Adding that `tenantId` property seems to eliminate the error.

Comment: Thx for this solution!

Comment: It didn't worked for so can anyone tell the issue in my case. Can anyone look  into this and tell me the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71701524/code-7505-error-request-authorization-tenant-mismatch
 @Marc LaFleur