# Code : 7505 ,Error - Request Authorization Tenant Mismatch

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, phone-call

It seems it is the common issue with all but there is no actual solution for anyone. Sometimes it work and some it gives. I am using the Eample 3 in the call create documentation of MS.
I am using BOT registration APP create for the call and below are the **https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/calls**

**NOTE** v1.0 is also tested instead of beta.

```js
    const client = await getApplicationClient(accessToken); // Application Token and not access token for API
const call = 
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
        "direction": "outgoing",
        "subject": "Call for Expert from Helpaas User",
        callbackUri: 'https://api.helpaas.com/v1/api/users/handleCallCallback',
         "source": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.participantInfo",
          "identity": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
            "application": {
              "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
              "displayName": "TestBot",
              "id": "71cf3107-2dc5-4385-8ac9-1aa686c25fb1"
            }
          }
        },
        "targets": [
          {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo",
            "identity": {
              "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
              "user": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
                    id: id.AAD_UserGuid,
                    displayName : id.DisplayName,
                    //"tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-f07acdb7cb58" Also tried to pass tenant id in usesr identity but not working
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "requestedModalities": [
          "audio"
        ],
        "mediaConfig": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig",
          "removeFromDefaultAudioGroup": false
        },
        "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-f07acdb7cb58"
      }

 const response = client.api(`/communications/calls`)
      .post(call);
      response.then(call=>{
          console.log("Call data--->> CAll ",call)
          // call.on
      }).catch(err=>{
          console.log("Eroor getting call data",err)
      })
return response;
```

**PAYLOAD**

```js
{
"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.call",
"callbackUri":"https://api.helpaas.com/v1/api/users/handleCallCallback",
"targets":[{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo","identity":{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.identitySet","user":{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.identity",
"id":"35128F4A-57C7-4279-A080-50D3D7F11547",
"displayName":"Uwe Gieb (Privat)",
"tenantId":"1b5002d5-a18c-4575-858e-f07acdb7cb58"
}
}
}],
"requestedModalities":["audio"],
"allowConversationWithoutHost":true,
"mediaConfig":{"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig"},
"tenantId":"1b5002d5-a18c-4575-858e-f07acdb7cb58"
}
```

**Error I am getting**

```
code: "7505"
innerError: {date: "2022-04-01T03:34:29", request-id: "27ea87b6-e819-4810-9d4d-e34e890b2b90",…}
client-request-id: "e3e060b3-69bc-1556-fe95-02ba91363b72"
date: "2022-04-01T03:34:29"
request-id: "27ea87b6-e819-4810-9d4d-e34e890b2b90"
message: "Request authorization tenant mismatch."
```

Extra Information reagrding configuration are below:
**BOT CONFIGURATION**
1.MS APP ID is same as of the app registration.
2. Tenant ID is also same.

[image]

**CHANNELS**
Just want to use teams for calling through graph api i.e "communication/calls" to a teams user.

[image]

**PERMISSIONS**
[image]

I passed the tenant ID at root level and also tried support team but nothing is working. If anyone can help me out it would really appreciating thing.

**NOTE : **Earlier it was working fine with the tenant used in the testing environment. With the production tenant it's not working at all.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the error it seems like the user and app are in different tenants, can you please check it once? Also sharing reference of a similar error - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7080?msclkid=c7c5a4fbb1a611ecb54abd514c9487e3

Comment: Well if the user and tenat are in the same tenant still I am getting the same error. Although I have tried passing the tenant Id in the user object I have tried with every soltution but it's not wokring so If you can check the issues . Please let me know I raised ticket couple of times but no response from MSFT support.

Comment: Can you please share the sample that you are using?

Comment: And what is actually you want in that sample? Should I provvide the configuration of BOT and application permissions. All the code is available above except Token from Azure that I can provide too..

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Provided some extra info you can check. Also the sample I am using is the first example in the create call.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#example-1-create-peer-to-peer-voip-call-with-service-hosted-media

Comment: As you have mentioned that it was working fine in the testing tenant, there could be an issue in the configuration for production tenant. Can you please verify it once again? meanwhile we will try and check the above-mentioned sample.

Comment: Sure but  I think I have rechecked it many a times now but I don't see anything difference now as per configuration. Its same except I have added monitor here and not enable the messaging or webchat as I don't requiere it. @Meghana-MSFT

Comment: If you can connecet let me know we can connect with Teams, and I can show you each and every  thing as per configuration and code so you can have better understanding of the flow and can help, You can find me with sanjeev,gupta@softobiz.com @Meghana-MSFT

Comment: We are checking this at our end. We will check and update you.

Comment: Sure but it's taking a lot time. Can you please make it more swift. Thanks @Meghana-MSFT

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Any luck so far. Please help me out of this if you can?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, we are checking the [calling meeting bot](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/v-abt/tab-coversations/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp) and there seems to be an issue with my configuration. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @Meghana-MSFT Let me know ASAP. Also please check with the latest Azure Bot in place of Bot Channel Registration as Bot Channel Registration has been replaced by Azure Bot.

Comment: We were able to setup the above mentioned [calling meeting](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/v-abt/tab-coversations/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp) bot sample and it is working fine at our end. We used Azure Bot only.

Comment: Could you please help us in having a local repro of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the error is in the request body. You are missing tenantId:

```js
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
  "callbackUri": "https://bot.contoso.com/callback",
  "targets": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo",
      "identity": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
        "user": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
          "displayName": "Demo User",
          "id": "{{UserId}}"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "requestedModalities": [
    "audio"
  ],
  "tenantId":"{{TenantID}}",
  "mediaConfig": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

•   As per the code posted by you for creating a call using a bot created in Azure, you are using variables in **‘targets’** section for **‘ID’** and **‘Display Name’**. Thus, I would suggest you to please use the **actual ID and Display Name of the user/application** to which the call is targeted. Thus, this will ensure that the source and destination targets for the Bot communication call are in the same tenant and the tenant mismatch error is avoided.

•   Also, would suggest you to please include the below line in **‘requestedModalities’** section before **‘tenantID’**: -

```
"meetingInfo": {
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.organizerMeetingInfo",
"organizer": {
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
  "user": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
    "id": "5810cede-f3cc-42eb-b2c1-e9bd5d53ec96",
    "displayName": "Bob",
    "tenantId":"86dc81db-c112-4228-9222-63f3esaa1edb"
  }
},
"allowConversationWithoutHost": true
},
 "tenantId":"86dc81db-c112-4228-9222-63f3esaa1edb"
}
```

This will ensure correctly specify the tenant in for which the call/meeting was made.

•   Kindly check the permissions below that need to be consented by a tenant administrator for calling bots with respect to **Microsoft Graph** which are necessary with regards to your error: -

[image: Permissions required]

For more information regarding this, kindly check the reference article below: -

https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/articles/calls/register-calling-bot.html

Comment: 1.Firstly,It doen't mean anything to make id and dsiplay name fields to be static as they keeps on changing as per the selected user to call.
2. Addong this "allowConversationWithoutHost": true does not make any change.
3. All the permission are perfectly provided in the image uploaded. I hope you can cross check in case of doubt.

Note : Also I have tried with static id and display name but it does not helped.
If you can connect please connect on sanjeev.gupta@softobiz.com via Teams.

Comment: I have added the payload to the question aksed so you can check that too.it is perfectly rendered i.e id and displaynames are replaced dynamically. @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT